# How do I return calculated Histogram results from OpenCV back to LabVIEW?

Tags: opencv, labview

I have no problems creating my DLL and sending images back & forth between LabVIEW and OpenCV DLL's.
Here is the code I am working with.

```
                #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
            #include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

            using namespace std;
            using namespace cv;

            // extern C
            extern "C" {

                _declspec (dllexport) int MyHistCalc(unsigned char *imageIN, int rows, int cols, double threshold1, double threshold2, int kernel_size, unsigned char *imageOUT, unsigned char *HistCalcImageOUT);
            }



            _declspec (dllexport) int MyHistCalc(unsigned char *imageIN,
                int rows,
                int cols,
                double threshold1,
                double threshold2,
                int kernel_size,
                unsigned char *imageOUT,
                unsigned char *HistCalcImageOUT) ...
```

I am unsure if my problem is catching image_histcalcoutput incorrectly in LabVIEW or returning result correctly.

[Please find screenshot of my VI attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jsEf.jpg)

Comment: HistCalcImageOUT is an image or an histogram?

Comment: it's a histograph (plot of a histogram)

Comment: as can be seen from my code snippet; I am trying to return 2 data sets back (to LabVIEW): imageOUT and HistCalcImageOUT. I tried simply by assigning these variables their values inside C++ code (as done previously with working example of one image) but this does not work. I get get images to be identical when received in LabVIEW. Any suggestions please?